# Eager loading and map in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I wanted to eagerly load a collection in rails and render it in json, I would have to do something like this.

```
@photos = @event.photos.to_json(:include => 
  {:appearances => {:include => :person}}
)
```

What if I wanted to map this collection? As you can see it's no longer a collection, but a json string. Prior to this necessary eager loading, I was doing the following:

```
@photos = @event.photos.map{|photo| 
  photo['some_funky_stuff'] = photo.funky_calculation
  photo 
}
```

But, I can't seem to be able to do the two things together:

```
@event.photos.map{|photo| 
  photo['some_funky_stuff'] = photo.funky_calculation
  photo 
}.to_json(:include => 
  {:appearances => {:include => :person}}
)
```

The above does not show 'appearances' ( the eagerly loaded join record )... How do I do these two together? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the term "eager loading" mixed up a little bit. As previous answers have mentioned, you need to use it on the association for it to be eager loaded. However, when you use `:include` in the to_json call, you will still end up with the same result, no matter if it is eager or not.

But to answer your question, for the to_json method to both include the appearances and the funky_calculation you can combine it with `:methods` instead. Try it like this:

```
@photos = @event.photos.to_json(
  :include => {:appearances => {:include => :person}},
  :methods => [: funky_calculation]
)
```

And if you want increased performance (eager loading), then use include on the associations as well:

```
@photos = @event.photos.includes(:appearances => :person).to_json(
  :include => {:appearances => {:include => :person}},
  :methods => [: funky_calculation]
)
```

Comment: here it adds funky_calculation as an attribute, but what if i wanted to map the record itself? for instance, i have an attribute called county which is derived by coordinates, how would I add country to the item itself instead of funky_calculation.county?

Comment: Well, if it is a record then you can put it in the :include hash together with appearances, but if you want county to be shown as an attribute in photos, then just created a method in the Photo class that calls funky_calculation.county and put that method in the :methods array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could eager load using `includes` after has_many association

```
@photos = @event.photos.includes(:appearances => [:person]).to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using `joins()` or `includes()` on photos, instead as an option to `to_json()`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations